# How to find same as using sub-query and set operation

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, set-operations

I am trying to get instructors who are teaching students that live in same zipcode as the instructor.

First I found what zipcodes were shared by students and instructors using intersect.

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,PHONE
FROM INSTRUCTOR 
 WHERE ZIP IN (
               SELECT ZIP 
               FROM STUDENT
               INTERSECT
               SELECT ZIP
               FROM INSTRUCTOR

                );
```

than how can I find the section_id's for all students that where in the query above ?

```
SELECT SECTION_ID   
FROM STUDENT s
JOIN ENROLLMENT e ON s.STUDENT_ID = e.STUDENT_ID
JOIN SECTION w ON e.SECTION_ID = w.SECTION_ID
JOIN INSTRUCTOR z ON w.INSTRUCTOR_ID = z.INSTRUCTOR_ID;
```

I dont know how to get inner query that would be something like INSTRUCTOR_ID.SECTION_ID = STUDENT_ID SECTION_ID,

Right now I am having in my query just returning all of the teachers who lived in that zipcode, but I also need to check for students that are taking a section that the instructors in that zip code are teaching....

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,PHONE
FROM
    (
SELECT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,PHONE,ZIP
FROM STUDENT 

    ) 
Derived
 WHERE ZIP IN (
               SELECT ZIP 
               FROM STUDENT
               INTERSECT
               SELECT ZIP
               FROM INSTRUCTOR

                );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT z.FIRST_NAME,z.LAST_NAME,z.PHONE
FROM STUDENT s
JOIN ENROLLMENT e ON s.STUDENT_ID = e.STUDENT_ID
JOIN SECTION w ON e.SECTION_ID = w.SECTION_ID
JOIN INSTRUCTOR z ON w.INSTRUCTOR_ID = z.INSTRUCTOR_ID AND s.ZIP = z.ZIP
```

Comment: I didnt know how to put them together thinking wise, I shouldve just put AND s.ZIP = z.ZIP which I did not think...thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Write a query that returns instructors and their students. Add the instructor and student zip codes. Add a predicate such that the zip codes must be the same.